# Where can I find the Lich King in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have looked all over Google and everyone says he's in the Icecrown Citadel but I can't find him anywhere. Where exactly can I find him?

Comment: http://www.wowhead.com/search?q=lich+king#npcs

Answer (score 17):

The Lich King can actually be found in many different places, including the Death Knight starter zone, several 5-man dungeons and appears as a result of many quests in Icecrown Citadel. If you level normally throughout the "Wrath of the Lich King" expansion, you will encounter him on several occasions.

To actually battle him, you need up to 25 other players in the Icecrown Citadel raid instance. For him to properly spawn, all three wing Guardians ([Sindragosa](http://www.wowpedia.org/Sindragosa_%28tactics%29), [Blood-Queen Lana'thel](http://www.wowpedia.org/Blood-Queen_Lana%27thel_%28tactics%29) and [Professor Putricide](http://www.wowpedia.org/Professor_Putricide)) must be downed. Doing so allows you to teleport to him through the center of the Citadel. I believe even if you somehow got up to the top of the Citadel, he will not spawn unless those preconditions are met.

Comment: wow how am i gonna get a group of 25 people. thanks for the info.

Comment: @Sarmen Well it is a raid instance. You can do it 10 man as well, or even as little as 5 if your level 85. This content was fresh a couple years back now so you missed the excitement.

Comment: It's been done solo by a death knight, but definitely not for the faint of heart.

Comment: killed the Lich King last weekend, definitely a challenge even in 10 man mode for a full team of lvl85 players who've not done it before. There's also a 5 man instance in Icecrown where you get to interact with him indirectly, but not fight him (you will see npcs fighting him).

Comment: It can be 5 manned with a decent group of players with Firelands gear on normal mode at 85 you can also 5man heroic bosses up to him easily.

Answer (score 7):

The Lich King is the final boss in the raid instance of Icecrown Citadel. Icecrown Citadel is located within the Icecrown zone - are you sure you're actually inside the dungeon, and not simply in the zone with the similar name?

Comment: i was in the zone not the raid area thats why.

Comment: @SarmenB. Great! Make sure to mark this as the accepted answer if you deem it has answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

The Lich King is inside of the IceCrown Citadel, in the Icecrown Zone of Northrend. Once you clear the other quarters, the final bosses of each Quarter make it possible to kill the Lich King. You will find him in the Upper Spire. Once you get there you can use teleporter at entrance if you need to go get more people to help you with him. Once you walk in the upper spire and go through another portal type device, you will be in a room with Highlord Tirion Fordring, and the Lich King on his frozen throne. Speaking with Tirion will start the 
[The Lich King Fight](http://www.wowwiki.com/Lich_King_(Icecrown_Citadel_tactics))

Good Luck!